# How to detect if SQL Server CE 4.0 is installed

Tags: c#, windows-installer, sql-server-ce-4

I develop some application that needs SQL Server CE 4.0 installed.

I do all job under Windows 7 64-bit so I have installed SQL Server CE 4.0 64-bit.

How I can do some checking if there is installed SQL Server CE 4.0 32-bit/64-bit when I start the application/or installer?

Which is the approach in general?

Any clue, articles and etc?

Thanks!!

P.S. I read this link [How can InstallShield check if SQL Server 2005 (3.1) Compact Edition (CE) is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969855/how-can-installshield-check-if-sql-server-2005-3-1-compact-edition-ce-is-ins) but it doesn't help.

Comment: I would have expected it's simply a matter of referencing the right assembly and ensuring it gets included in the setup.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx "You can simply copy the SQL CE binaries"

Comment: @spender The problem is that I have reference to the 64-bit version, but in fact application should check if it is 32-bit or 64-bit version.

Comment: If you're looking to go "cross platform", i.e. x86/x64, why not just publish a 32 bit binary. Is there any reason why you need to specifically release for x64?

Comment: @spender I mean I need some approach to detect if SQL Server CE is installed by registry or somehow... and which version is installed and for which platform and etc..

Comment: @Peretz - As we already suggested publish both the x86 assembly and the x64 assembly.  Simple process to determine which file you actually want to use.  From there if you attempt to connect to a database.  Another solution is to have your installer install CE 4.0 if its not already installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just include all the required files with your app, and it will run on both x86 and x64 - see my blog post here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/02/using-sql-server-compact-40-with.html

You can also use code below to detect if the runtime is available to your app, but not required if yu implement above:

```
        public bool IsV40Installed()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91");
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        try
        {
            var factory = System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0");
        }
        catch (System.Configuration.ConfigurationException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentException)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```