# does SQL Server compact 4.0 requries sql server installed

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce-4

I'm doing some testing with sql server compact 4.0 added into an mvc application.  do you know if this is required to be installed on an sql server 8.0 when i deploy to web server or does the compact version come with a pre-built sql server engine, no does not require moving it to a sql server 8.0?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534158/how-to-detect-if-sql-server-ce-4-0-is-installed?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create installer and you can check whether Sql server compact edition already installed or not. there are few options to install the compact edition by installer. from windows updated or adding dlls with the project. Read [How to: Deploy a SQL Server Compact 4.0 Database with an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983326.aspx) for more information. There is no requirement to have sql server installed on your server.